# Can I convert a json input to a list of objects within jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and just playing for fun. I have some [code](https://github.com/balancemedia/Timeline) that I want to try to modify for my needs but the current js file is getting its data from google spreadsheets and then returning each item as objects. I don't use json to pass data from my server to jQuery so I'm wondering how I can convert json to objects.

The current way its doing it is(tabletop is the name of their js program that gets data from google docs):

```
Tabletop.init({
    key: timelineConfig.key,
    callback: setupTimeline,
    wanted: [timelineConfig.sheetName],
    postProcess: function(el){
        //alert(el['photourl']);
        el['timestamp'] = Date.parse(el['date']);
        el['display_date'] = el['displaydate'];
        el['read_more_url'] = el['readmoreurl'];
        el['photo_url'] = el['photourl'];
    }
});
```

I have added alerts all over the file and I think this is the area that gets the data and passes it on. I was thinking of trying to replace items in their object with objects from my json and see if it changes anything, but I'm unsure.  Typrically I pass individual items via json,hashmaps, and lists, not sure how it works with objects or how to access objects(I simply call url's that I create for the requests, `$("#user-history").load("/cooltimeline/{{ user.id }}");`).   But where do I start if I want to turn json data into objects?

If it helps, here's the [demo](http://builtbybalance.com/github-timeline/) of what I'm trying to do(but by having it use json data).

p.s. I'm really looking for the logic of how to complete what I'm trying to do and perhaps some ideas I'm missing so I can google them and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use use function `JSON.parse(json)` :) Or `jQuery.parseJSON(json)`

```
var json = '{"a":2}';
var object = JSON.parse(json);

alert(object.a);
```

You should see alert with message: `2`

---

I don't realy know if I understand your comment, but maybe you want just do this:

```
   postProcess: function(el){ //here el is JSON string
        el = JSON.parse(el); // now el is an object
        el.timestamp = Date.parse(el.date);
        el.display_date = el.displaydate;
        el.read_more_url = el.readmoreurl;
        el.photo_url = el.photourl;

        return el;

    }
```

Btw. you do not need to use brackets on know property names without not standard names:

```
el['timestamp'] === el.timestamp
```

It will be easier if you paste your JSON

Comment: Its not really working.  What I tried to do was create a alert for each of the above variables and then try to use your approach to replace all the variables with my own data to see if I can change the page but its just not loading(just blank where the timeline is suppose to be)

Comment: If I understand you the `el` in your `postProcess` function is that JSON? If if is then you shoud use something like: `el = JSON.parse(el)`. In what browser you testing that app?

Comment: I just tried that, no luck.  I'm testing in chrome.  I left the above code the same but above it I added `var el = '{"date":"may 15, 2008"}';
 var el = JSON.parse(el);`  and did a alert to see if the data was coming through and its not. My goal is to manuelly enter some data so I understand how it works then I'll connect it to my server via json

Comment: I know that works but I'm trying to get it into this variable(in the part in the code above): `el['timestamp'] = Date.parse(el['date']);`  so if I do `alert(el['date']); ` it outputs may 15, 2008

Comment: I've look at Tabletop code and now I know that you're doing it wrong ;) That library use Google Spreadsheet to load data, and function `parseProcess` is just for maping column names to data in sheet. If you want to use JSON instead of Google, you need to change Tabletop library.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.   I'm new to jquery but I thought I tabletop was getting the data from google and returning objects so I was trying to figure a way to avoid using that file completely and just getting the script.js use some json objects. Can I modify `parseProcess ` to map some json objects instead of google?

Comment: Tabletop use JSONP comunication with Google - if you change `line 63` in tabletop.js from google address into your url and provide JSONP feature on that url it should works fine, but I don't promise it to you ;) I'm just guessing

Comment: ahhh your a genius!  I didn't think of that..I'll try to change url and the mapping and report back.

Comment: Hey Thanks again but I'm still having problems.  I did a bit of research and jsonp seems to be used for cross domain requests, since my request is from my domain I was thinking about using just plain json.   If you look at https://github.com/balancemedia/Timeline/blob/master/js/script.js can't I replace the top tabletop request and replace it with my own json calls?

Comment: JSONP is nothing like `JSON with callback`. Instead of writing `{"a":2}` yow write `callback({"a":2})` where `callback` is name of function pased from request. Then that response is injected into source and `callback` function will be called automaticly. Yes, you can change it for normal JSON, but you will need to provide own `callback` execution method.

Comment: If you want change JSONP for JSON you need to change in https://github.com/balancemedia/Timeline/blob/master/js/tabletop.js function `injectScript` in `line 98`. You can use for example jQuery `$.ajax` function and use `success` method to fire callback pased in arguments of `injectScript`.